# How to fetch data from model when another model is selected?

Tags: model, yii

I have created one model for Event Categories, and another model for Events. When user will select any particular event category, I want to display all the events under that category.

The following are the relations I've given to their models.
EventCategory.php Model:

```
return array(
    'event' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Event', 'event_category_id'),
);
```

Event.php Model:

```
return array(
     'category' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'EventCategory', 'event_category_id'),
);
```

When I try to return events in event category view, **NOT SET** is returned.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
'data'=>$model,
'attributes'=>array(
    'evntcatm_id',
    'evntcatm_name',
    'evntcatm_desc',
    'evntcatm_img',
    'event.evntm_evntcatm_id',
    'event.evntm_name',
),
)); ?>
```

Where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation `event` int your category is a `HAS_MANY`. So `$category->event` will be an array of `Event` records. So how should Yii know, what to do with that list of objects? You could add getters to your `Category` model, though. For example for the event names:

```
public function getEventNames()
{
    $names = array();
    foreach($this->events as $event) {
         $names[] = $event->eventm_name;
    }
    return implode(', ', $names);
}
```

And then use `eventNames` in your detailview as if it where a regular category attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I have used loadModel to fetch the *Category ID* and then this pass ID to dataProvider to compare the data from database and returned the results.

EventCategoryController.php

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $this->layout = 'main';
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('evntm_sts','a',true);
    $criteria->compare('evntm_evntcatm_id',$model->evntcatm_id,true);

    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Event', array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

In View:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_event',
    'summaryText'=> '',
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are trying to return a list of events with the event category information populated.  Instead of going at it from the event category, I would go at it from the event.  Then you can access the event category information with a shortcut.  Something like this:

In the controller

```
$model = Event::model()->fetchAll();
```

Then in the view your attributes array would look like

```
'attributes' => array(
   'category.evntcatm_id',
   'category.evntcatm_name',
    ...
   'evntm_evntcatm_id',
   'evntm_name',
),
```